# Error trying to write a data frame to a sas7bdat file in R

Tags: r, r-haven

I am working with a `data.frame` in `R` that I want to export (write) as a sas7bdat file. The package that I am using is `haven`

when I use the command line:

```
write_sas(df, "newsasdata.sas7bdat")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in write_sas_(data, normalizePath(path, mustWork = FALSE)) : 
  Writing failure: A row of data will not fit into the file format.
```

Comment: What exactly is in this data.frame? It would be easier to help you if you provided some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't know R, but the data of the variable `df` must be important in the question. Can you paste some of it in your question?

Comment: Oh man, I was afraid of that... Unfortunately, is data from a project that I can't share... I just was wondering if someone had an idea why that could be happening. I totally understand if it is impossible without the original data that is in the vector df.